# passing multiple arguments trough a pipe

Tags: command-line

I've got an command, that outputs infinite lines of this format:

```
$cmd1
word1 text with spaces and so on
word2 another text with spaces and so on
```

I want to pass every line to another command so that the first `word` will be passed to one argument and the rest of the text will be passed to another argument. like so:

```
$cmd2 --argword=word1 --argtext="text with spaces and so on"
$cmd2 --argword=word2 --argtext="another text with spaces and so on"
```

Comment: You'll probably have to cobble together some sort of shim that sits between the first command and the second, so that it can parse the output of the first in order to compose the input for the second.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the ultimate line has a newline (otherwise that line gets lost) and that `cmd2` is set to something sensible a shell code cobbled shim might look something like

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=" "
while read word andtherest; do
    $cmd2 --argword="$word" --argtext="$andtherest"
done
```

as the leftover fields should all be lumped into `andtherest` per how `read` behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Try a little awk:

```
/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    cmd=$1;
    gsub($1 " +", "")
    printf("%s --argword=%s --argtext=\"%s\"\n", cmd2, cmd, $0)
}
```

That output accepts an awk variable as the name for *cmd2*.

You can test it this way:

```
$ echo "word1 text with spaces and so on" | 
  awk -v cmd2=foo '{ cmd=$1; gsub($1 " +", ""); printf("%s --argword=%s --argtext=\"%s\"\n", cmd2, cmd, $0) }'
foo --argword=word1 --argtext="text with spaces and so on"
```